# sql query returning invalid rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables like t_zip5,t_dtv_cnty_eligibility,t_user_activity.
I will fetch all zipcodes from t_zip5 tables based on countyId.

These zipcodes will be looked-up in zip column of t_user_activity table.If zip matches I will have to fetch the cuid and actvty columns else I will have to keep those columns empty or null for the zip code of t_zip5 table.

I have written the below query:

```
select distinct tz.zip,td.DTV_eligible,tu.cuid,tu.actvty_date
from T_ZIP5 tz,T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY td,T_USER_ACTIVITY tu 
where tz.FIPS_CNTY='51001' 
and tz.FIPS_CNTY=td.CNTY_FIPS 
and tz.zip=tu.zip
```

This query provides only matched rows of zipcode. I have to fetch rows for other zip codes of county also even if it is not matched.

Ex: County 51001 has 40 zipcodes. The above query resulted me only 3 rows as zip entry matched for those 3 zips.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Table Structures:

```
desc t_zip5
Name              Null     Type         
----------------- -------- ------------ 
ZIP               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)  
FIPS_CNTY                  VARCHAR2(5)  
CITY_NAME         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
STATE             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(2)  
RATE_CENTER_NAME           VARCHAR2(10) 
RATE_CENTER_STATE          VARCHAR2(2)  

desc T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY
Name          Null     Type         
------------- -------- ------------ 
CNTY_FIPS     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)  
ZIP_CODE      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)  
DTV_ELIGIBLE           CHAR(1)      
USER_MODIFIED          VARCHAR2(10) 
CREATED_DATE           DATE         
MODIFIED_DATE          DATE         

desc t_user_activity

    Name        Null Type          
    ----------- ---- ------------- 
    ACTVTY_DATE      DATE          
    ACTVTY_NAME      VARCHAR2(20)  
    ACTVTY_DSCR      VARCHAR2(200) 
    CUID             VARCHAR2(10)  
    ZIP              VARCHAR2(5)
```

Sample output:

```
ZIP  DTV_Eligible  CUID  MODIFIED_DATE
----------- ---- ----------------------
1111     Y         xyz    05-02-2015
1111     N         xyz    05-02-2015
2222     Y         abc    02-02-2015
2222     N         abc    02-02-2015
```

Comment: Replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN and see what happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Left join. Inner join will return only matched values.

```
select distinct tz.zip,td.DTV_eligible,tu.cuid,tu.actvty_date
from T_ZIP5 tz left join T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY td on tz.FIPS_CNTY=td.CNTY_FIPS 
left join T_USER_ACTIVITY tu on tz.zip=tu.zip
where tz.FIPS_CNTY='51001'
```

Comment: Now I am getting 80 rows returned. Because DTV_eligible column of T_DTV_CNTY_ELIGIBILITY table has values 'Y' and 'N'. So, instead of 40 rows I get 80 rows. Please help me again

Comment: @PriyaViji - which column has those values, `DTV_eligible`? You're including that in the select list so at the moment you're expecting to see both values, and hence both records. If you only want one then include a filter for either Y or N in the outer join condition; but then there isn't much point having it in the select list?

Comment: @AlexPoole - If I filter based on Y or N, I wont get the true results. Is there any other way to overcome this situation

Comment: @PriyaViji - you need to add some sample data, current output and desired output and the logic you want to apply; but it might need to be a new question since this answer already addresses what you asked for in this question and that would be too big a change, I think. But you seem to be asking for two mutually-exclusive things.

Comment: @PriyaViji - I meant too big a change *to this question*. It's not good to change a question so much that it invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @PriyaViji . . . This answers the question you asked.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a question not in a comment.